# What is the difference between creating the Container using Blob storage Service REST API and StorageClient class library in azure storage service?

Tags: azure, cloud, blob

What is the difference between creating the Container using  REST APIs and StorageClient class library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer experience is the only difference.  The StorageClient uses REST under the covers.  REST is the only API for storage and the client just takes care of the nitty gritty stuff (canonicalization, signing, setting up HTTP request, etc.).